# Prefix '0' to the int variable which less than '10', How?

Tags: string, methods, c#-2.0, int

Is there any simple method to concatenate '0' before an int variable.

Like:

```
int i = 2;

// produce    
i = someMethod(i);

// output:
i = 02
```

Comment: Can somebody please explain what "contaminate '0'" means?

Comment: Do you want to print i as 02? I don't understant the term contaminate. Do you mean prepend or prefix, or concate?

Comment: I think OP means 'concatenate'.

Comment: @All, contaminate  should be *concatenate*. Sorry for my original input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean "concatenate", then you can define someMethod() as follows:

```
string someMethod(int i){
  return string.Format("{0:d2}", i);
}
```

The "2" in the string format defines the number of characters in the output.

Comment: To throw my two cents worth: return i.ToString("0#"); will also work